# How do I best make calculations per slice in a row and save the output as new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My question relates to how I would make calculations for each row in a pandas dataframe, but on slices of each row, and then output the resulting calculations as a new dataframe that I can save as a txt file.

For example, lets say I want to output a dataframe  that has the mean values (for each row) for the data in columns 0, 1 and 2 and a mean value for columns 3, 4 and 5.

I found how to slice columns and this is what I came up with so far (just running it on row 0).

```
for i in df:
  if i == 0:
     a = df.ix[:,0:3].mean()
     b = df.ix[:,3::].mean()

print a, b
```

output is something like this:

```
0    0.000002
1    0.000001
2    0.000001
3    0.000002
dtype: float64 3    0.000002
4    0.000001
5    0.000001 
6    0.000002
7    0.000001
dtype: float64
```

My questions are:

1) I don't understand this output since I expected only two numbers: the mean of the first slice (a) and the mean of the second slice (b).. Where am I going wrong, or is this not the right way to approach this task?

2) how can I store the result in a new dataframe and save it as txt file

Comment: First: `for i in df` loops through the column names -- not rows -- of the dataframe. So you definitely don't want that. Second, `ix` has been more or less deprecated. Use `loc` and `iloc` instead. Third, you almost never need to loop through pandas objects. See my response for a more efficient way.

Comment: Fourth, you're not using `i` within the loop at all, so when you take away the `if` statement, the same statement will be computed for each iteration. Fifth, calling the `mean` method on the default axis (0) will compute the mean of the columns. If you want a single value for the whole dataframe (or a selected subset), use `df.mean().mean()`.

Comment: wow.. that clears up a lot! Thank you.. I almost don't dare to ask, but I want to store the result in a new dataframe, would I just make a new one and then use that to assign the result to (on line 5 of your answer)? How do I initialize an dataframe to do so?

Comment: that makes sense.. very welcomed.. What I did after that to save it is `means.to_csv("test.csv")` 
Is there a txt (tab-delimited) writer function too by any chance that you know of? (I couldn't find it).

Comment: see my edits. `.to_csv` take a value for the separator. `'\t'` is the value you want for that.

Comment: this helps me understand the basic concept of the work that I will be doing a lot, but there's so much more.. I'll have to study and write more questions. (Hope you'll be around ;-)) Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any loops. With pandas, if you're looping, you're probably doing something very wrong. Just select all the rows and subset of columns with the `iloc` attribute and call the `mean` method with `axis=1`:

```
import pandas
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(0)
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.round(numpy.random.normal(size=(10, 5)),2))
means = pandas.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, :3].mean(axis=1), columns=['means'])
print(means)

        means
0    1.046667
1   -0.060000
2    0.783333
3    0.536667
4   -0.346667
5   -0.530000
6   -0.120000
7    0.863333
8   -1.393333
9   -0.303333
dtype: float64
```

You have to explicitly make `means` a dataframe since the `mean` method returns a series.

To save it as tab-delimited text file, use: `means.to_csv('means.txt', sep='\t')`